# How to automatically add components from a nuget package?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I've packaged my custom controls into a nuget package and published it. When I add the package to a project, the controls are not added to the toolbox.

The setting `Automatically Populate Toolbox` is set to `true` (Tools -> Options -> Windows Form Designer)

The custom controls have class attributes such as:

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TextBox))]
[DefaultBindingProperty("Text")]
```

The only way to get the controls in the toolbox is by browsing for the `dll` in the `packages` folder and adding it to the toolbox.

But is there a more cleaner way whereby the controls are automatically added to the toolbox after the package is installed (or updated)?

Comment: Please leave a comment here so that this issue gets visibility: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3509#issuecomment-337100601

Comment: I have sunk half a week into a workaround you might find useful for the present: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3509#issuecomment-347621114